# Multiprocessing a for loop that appends to a pandas data frame with multiple arguments

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, multiprocessing

I am trying to figure out a way to multi process this function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas 


#csv, dfew1

def dataframe_iterator(csv, dfnew1):
    for item in csv['Trips_Tbl_ID'].unique():
            # creating a temporary file for each unique trip table ID
            dftemp = traveL_time(item, 'all')
            # appending the temporary file to a new file
            dfnew1 = dfnew1.append(dftemp)

    return dfnew1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = [(csv), (dfnew1)]
    start_time = time.time()

    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(dataframe_iterator, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Some context:

'csv' is a huge dataframe with a bunch of jumbled up transportation records and a lot of non unique trip table ids. It has already been called in the jupyter notebook.

For every unique trip table ID in the csv, I am applying a computation heavy custom made function called traveL_time to transform it and condense it.

'dfnew1' is a custom made empty dataframe with the exact same structure that a dataframe would have after the traveL_time function is applied to 'csv', which is why I'm appending to it in the for loop. It has already been called in the jupyter notebook.

I am pretty new to python and I'm having some trouble with speeding up runtime because it's really a massive dataset, and it takes about 9 minutes to go over 150k records in 'csv' currently, and I have to eventually go over hundreds of millions of records.

My question is how would I be able to multi process this function using the two arguments csv and dfnew1 to potentially speed this up?

I have tried using pandarallel but I am getting a lot of errors, and I'm not quite sure how to go about using multiple arguments for the multi processing library. Also this current setup seems to be going on forever and I'm sure it's wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: if you want to send two elements to function then you have to create list of pairs - `[(cvs[0], dfnew1), (cvs[1], dfnew1), ... ]` and use `starmap` to assign `cvs[0]`, `dfnew1` to  `dataframe_iterator(csv, dfnew1)`. Every process will use own copy of `dfnew1` and need to get results `results = pool.map(dataframe_iterator, csv)` and later convert `results` to one `dataframe`.

Comment: you have `map(dataframe_iterator, [(csv), (dfnew1)])` and (if I'm not wrong) it should run it as two processes `dataframe_iterator(csv)` and `dataframe_iterator(dfnew1)` so it send data in different way as you expect and it send all `csv` to one process - and it means it has to save all `csv` in file, run process and process has to read all `csv` from file - so it need a lot of time to work with files.